# gh-pages across Github projects all link to domain

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I'm using GitHub Pages and Jekyll on my repository and have linked the repository to my own URL. 
So, **rimager.github.io** links to **rimagerhard.com**

When I create a new repo and push to the gh-pages branch, that repo becomes available under my URL as well. For instance, I pushed to my literary-quotes gh-pages branch and poof, it's all up under http://www.rimagerhard.com/literary-quotes/

Could someone explain to me why this is happening? I am feeling a bit obtuse today. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you set a custom domain on Github, it sets a permanent redirect from **rimager.github.io** to **rimagerhard.com**.

As **rimager.github.io/literary-quotes** is considered as part of the domain, the redirection applies.

Comment: So all of my Github project will be considered part of the domain from now on (if they have a gh-pages branch)?

Comment: Yes they will. And I think you cannot go back to username.github.io on this account without removing the CNAME on you user repository.